# Get files from filesytem which can be found in any level deep subfolders

Tags: marklogic

I am using ML 5 and want to ingest/load documents from local file system to MarkLogic DB. I have created recursive function with the help of xdm;:filesystem-directory() function to check folder depth. But, I am getting XDMP-STACKOVERFLOW error. My file system folder has multiple folder with multiple sub-folder in multiple depth. for example

```
├───vol_18
│   ├───iss_1
│   ├───iss_2
│   ├───iss_3
│   ├───iss_4
│   ├───iss_5
│   └───iss_6
├───vol_19
│   ├───iss_1
│   ├───iss_2
│   ├───iss_3
│   ├───iss_4
│   ├───iss_5
│   └───iss_6
├───vol_2
│   ├───iss_1
│   ├───iss_2
│   ├───iss_3
│   ├───iss_4
│   ├───iss_5
│   └───iss_6
```

Is there any other better way to get files recursively from local file system?

My Codes are:

```
declare function IngestArchive($WhichFolder)
{
  let $FileToIngest := ""
  let $Collection := tokenize($WhichFolder, '\\')[last()]
  for $EachFolder in xdmp:filesystem-directory($WhichFolder)/dir:entry
  return
    if( $EachFolder[dir:type='directory'] )
    then
      let $Result := HasFolder($WhichFolder)
      return xdmp:set($FileToIngest, <File>{$Result/dir:pathname/string()}</File>)
    else
      xdmp:set($FileToIngest, <File>{$EachFolder/dir:pathname/string()}</File>)
};

declare function HasFolder($WhichFolder)
{
  for $EachFolder in xdmp:filesystem-directory($WhichFolder)/dir:entry[1]
  return
    if( $EachFolder[dir:type='directory'] )
    then
      HasFolder($WhichFolder)
    else
      <File>{$EachFolder/dir:pathname/string()}</File>
};
```

Please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an endless loop. Your `HasFolder` function calls itself, but with original argument. I think you want this:

```
HasFolder($WhichFolder)
```

to be replaced with:

```
HasFolder($EachFolder)
```

HTH!